# Convergence in distribution - Gamma distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

If we have a random variable defined as $Y_{n}=\displaystyle\frac{X_n-n\alpha}{n\alpha^2}$, where $X_n$ is $\operatorname{Gamma}(n,\alpha)$ distribution, how can I prove that $Y_n$ converges in distribution as $n \to \infty$ ? And what's the limiting distribution?

$\operatorname{Gamma}(n, \alpha)$ is defined as

$$\begin{cases}\frac{1}{\alpha^n \Gamma{(n)}}x^{n-1}e^{-x/\alpha} &\text{if } x\geqslant 0 ,& \\ 1 & \text{if } x<0.\end{cases}$$

Comment: There are different conventional meanings attached to $\text{Gamma}(n,\alpha)$ (see e.g. the Wikipedia entry on gamma random variables) and unless you tell is which one you are using, the question cannot be answered. One convention makes $E[X_n]=n\alpha$, $\operatorname{var}(X_n)=n\alpha^2$.  So, $Z_n = \frac{X_n-n\alpha}{\sqrt{n}\alpha}=\sqrt{n}\alpha Y_n$ is a zero-mean unit variance random variable.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to calculate the limit is to remark that $X_n$ has the same distribution as $\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i$ where the $Z_i$'s are iid exponential random variables with parameter $\alpha$. So, the central limit theorem states that
$$ \frac{X_n - n \alpha}{\sqrt n \ \alpha} \overset d \longrightarrow  \mathcal N(0,1).  $$ 
So $Y_n$ converges to zero...